# krb5-multidev, libk5crypto3, libk5crypto3:i386 package dependency

Tags: package-management, kerberos

Using Ubuntu 12.04
Asus U43F

I can no longer update, install or remove packages via software center because of package dependency errors.

`sudo apt-get install -f` reads the following:

```
    Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libunity6 libqapt-runtime libboost-program-options1.46.1
  akonadi-backend-mysql libqapt1 shared-desktop-ontologies libntrack0
  ntrack-module-libnl-0 libntrack-qt4-1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  krb5-multidev libk5crypto3:i386 libkrb5-dev
Suggested packages:
  krb5-doc krb5-doc:i386 krb5-user:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  krb5-multidev libk5crypto3:i386 libkrb5-dev
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 325 not upgraded.
11 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/213 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: error processing libk5crypto3 (--configure):
 libk5crypto3:amd64 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3 cannot be configured because libk5crypto3:i386 is in a different version (1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.1)
dpkg: error processing libk5crypto3:i386 (--configure):
 libk5crypto3:i386 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.1 cannot be configured because libk5crypto3:amd64 is in a different version (1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3)
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkrb5-3:
 libkrb5-3 depends on libk5crypto3 (>= 1.9+dfsg~beta1); however:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

  Package libk5crypto3 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libkrb5-3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgssapi-krb5-2:
 libgssapi-krb5-2 depends on libk5crypto3 (>= 1.8+dfsg); however:
  Package libk5crypto3 is not configured yet.
 libgssapi-krb5-2 depends on libkrb5-3 (= 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3); however:
  Package libkrb5-3 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libgssapi-krb5-2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgssrpc4:
 libgssrpc4 depends on libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.10+dfsg~); however:
  Package libgssapi-krb5-2 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libgssrpc4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkadm5srv-mit8:
 libkadm5srv-mit8 depends on libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2); however:
  Package libgssapi-krb5-2 is not configured yet.
 libkadm5srv-mit8 depends on libgssrpc4 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2); however:
  Package libgssrpc4 is not configured yet.
 libkadm5srv-mit8 depends on libk5crypto3 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2); however:
  Package libk5crypto3 is not configured yet.
 libkadm5srv-mit8 depends on libkrb5-3 (>= 1.9+dfsg~beta1); however:
  Package libkrb5-3 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libkadm5srv-mit8 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkadm5clnt-mit8:
 libkadm5clnt-mit8 depends on libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.10+dfsg~); however:
  Package libgssapi-krb5-2 is not configured yet.
 libkadm5clnt-mit8 depends on libgssrpc4 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2); however:
  Package libgssrpc4 is not configured yet.No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 libkadm5clnt-mit8 depends on libk5crypto3 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2); however:
  Package libk5crypto3 is not configured yet.
 libkadm5clnt-mit8 depends on libkrb5-3 (>= 1.8+dfsg); however:
  Package libkrb5-3 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libkadm5clnt-mit8 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of krb5-multidev:
 krb5-multidev depends on libkrb5-3 (= 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.2); however:
  Version of libkrb5-3 on system is 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3.
 krb5-multidev depends on libk5crypto3 (= 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.2); however:
  Version of libk5crypto3 on system is 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3.
 krb5-multidev depends on libgssapi-krb5-2 (= 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.2); however:
  Version of libgssapi-krb5-2 on system is 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3.
 krb5-multidev depends on libgssrpc4 (= 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.2); however:
  Version of libgssrpc4 on system is 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3.
 krb5-multidev depends on libkadm5srv-mit8 (= 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.2); however:
  Version of libkadm5srv-mit8 on system is 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3.
 krb5-multidev depends on libkadm5clnt-mit8 (= 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.2); however:
  Version of libkadm5clnt-mit8 on system is 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3.
dpkg: error processing krb5-multidev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkrb5-dev:
 libkrb5-dev depends on krb5-multidev (= 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.2); however:
  Package krb5-multidev is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libkrb5-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkrb5-3:i386:
 libkrb5-3:i386 depends on libk5crypto3 (>= 1.9+dfsg~beta1); however:
  Package libk5crypto3:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libkrb5-3:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgssapi-krb5-2:i386:
 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 depends on libk5crypto3 (>= 1.8+dfsg); however:
  Package libk5crypto3:i386 is not configured yet.
 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 depends on libkrb5-3 (= 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3); however:
  Package libkrb5-3:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libk5crypto3
 libk5crypto3:i386
 libkrb5-3
 libgssapi-krb5-2
 libgssrpc4
 libkadm5srv-mit8
 libkadm5clnt-mit8
 krb5-multidev
 libkrb5-dev
 libkrb5-3:i386
 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried to fix the broken dependencies via synaptic package manager, but it returns with an error:

```
E: libk5crypto3: libk5crypto3:amd64 1.10+dfsg~beta1-2ubuntu0.3 cannot be configured because libk5crypto3
E: libkrb5-3: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libgssapi-krb5-2: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libgssrpc4: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libkadm5srv-mit8: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libkadm5clnt-mit8: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: krb5-multidev: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: libkrb5-dev: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

I haven't gotten help from ubuntuforums.org on this issue. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try This. Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```